# How to check if the Date conforms to a specific DateFormat without using Exception?

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I am aware that parse() can be used for knowing if the valid date conforms to a specific format. But that throws exception in case of a failure. I wanted just to verify if the date is of a specific format. Especially I need a boolean result from this comparison. How to achieve that in Java?

Comment: Not of any that I know of. You need to create one for yourself that uses parse(). You need to return false if an exception is caught. If the parsing succeeds, return true.

Comment: @Prashant Avoiding exceptions in validation is possible (since Java 1.0), see my answer.

Comment: @Meno Hochschild. Right! Nice one. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3):

I am wondering why nobody here knows following **standard validation using `ParsePosition`**. Programming based on exception logic is more or less evil.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
sdf.setLenient(false);
ParsePosition pp = new ParsePosition(0);
java.util.Date d = sdf.parse("02/29/2015", pp);

if (d == null) {
    System.out.println("Error occurred at position: " + pp.getErrorIndex());
    return false;
} else {
    return true; // valid
}
```

Note that it is important to **use the strict mode**!

A little bit out of scope of the question but interesting:

The new `java.time`-library (JSR-310) [does force the user to code against exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.text.ParsePosition-) - a clear regression compared with 'SimpleDateFormat`. The problem of catching exceptions is generally bad performance which can be relevant if you parse bulk data with lower quality.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you want to write regular expression which you can match against your date format I am afraid there is no other way than catching `ParseException`.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static Scanner s;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(checkDateFormat("2000-01-01"));
}

// Checks if the date meets the pattern and returns Boolean
// FORMAT yyyy-mm-dd RANGE : 2000-01-01 and 2099-12-31
public static Boolean checkDateFormat(String strDate) {

    if (strDate.matches("^(19|20)\\d\\d[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$")) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This solution right here uses Regex Patterns to validate the date format (No Exceptions needed as there is no need for any because you are not using the SimpleDateFormat Parse() method). For more information/help about regular expressions and dates visit http://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html.

Comment: Thanks for this. By the way, I assume the range is from `1900-01-01` to `2099-12-31`, isn't it?